# Featherlight JS Creates Duplicate ID's in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hide div content with css `display: none;` and display it with a [Featherlight](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#usage) window.

I have some id's in the content that are accessed by other JavaScript.

The problem is that when Featherlight creates a modal window from my hidden div, the id is duplicated. One in the hidden div, one in the window.

Now JS controls only see the id in the hidden div and not in the Featherlight window. So nothing works inside the window.

How do I get around this?

https://jsfiddle.net/fpunL1nk/ (window doesn't cover the screen in jsfiddle)

**JS**

```
<!-- Featherlight Button -->
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#window">Open Featherlight</a>

<!-- Featherlight Window -->
<div class="hidden">
  <div id="window">
      <div id="content">
        This ID is duplicated.
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

id="content" is duplicated.

**CSS**

```
.hidden { 
  display:none; 
 }
#window { 
  width:400px;
  height:250px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
You can disable the source HTML inputs when you opened the dialog, so only the input inside the popup would be sent to the server on form submission.